# how to use macro to replace assignment operation for use in locking a function

Tags: c++, macros

At the beginning of a function, I call this macro to prevent re-entrance into the function:

```
//For locking ISRs to prevent re-entrant execution when nested interrupts are enabled 
//-ex: to prevent re-entrant execution of this ISR even though ***nested interrupts are enabled!***
//-"return" is to exit the function if the ISR is locked 
#define functionLock()              \
  static bool ISR_locked = false;   \
  if (ISR_locked==true)             \
    return;                         \
  ISR_locked = true;                \
```

This works.

At the end of the function I want to use this macro to re-enable the function for the next entrance into it:

```
#define functionUnlock() ISR_locked = false;
```

But, that fails to compile. Errors:

```
error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
error: 'functionLock' was not declared in this scope
error: 'ISR_locked' was not declared in this scope
```

**What is wrong with my 2nd macro?**

If I just remove the 2nd macro and use "ISR_locked = false;" directly at the end of the function, it all works fine, but I want to have a matching macro to end the function, rather than using that line.

The goal is to use these macros in a function, like this:

```
void myISR()
{
  functionLock(); //locks the function to prevent re-entrant execution
  //do stuff
  functionUnlock();
}
```

---

Full minimal example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//macros:
//For locking ISRs to prevent re-entrant execution when nested interrupts are enabled
//-ex: to prevent re-entrant execution of this ISR even though ***nested interrupts are enabled!***
//-"return" is to exit the function if the ISR is locked
#define functionLock()              \
  static bool ISR_locked = false;   \
  if (ISR_locked==true)             \
    return;                         \
  ISR_locked = true;                \
#define functionUnlock() ISR_locked = false;

void myISR()
{
  functionLock();
  cout << "hello";
  functionUnlock();
//  ISR_locked = false;
}

int main()
{
  myISR();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd be much better off creating an object that took the lock in the constructor and released in the destructor - then you wouldn't need to remember to call `functionUnlock()`.

Comment: @TonyD, can you point me to a good example? The whole concept of locking a function is a new area for me. PS. This is running on an ATmega328 microcontroller (Arduino).

Comment: Try `struct ScopedLock { ScopedLock(bool& b) : b_(b) { b = true; } ~ScopedLock() { b_ = false; } bool& b_; };`, then in your `functionLock` macro, replace `ISR_locked = true;` with `ScopedLock isrLocker(&ISR_locked);`.

Comment: Do you need to worry about the apparent race condition?  The first thread reads `ISR_locked==false`, but before gets to where it sets `ISR_locked=true`, a second thread sneaks in because it also reads `ISR_locked==false`.  I know I'm not aware of much of the code's context, but I usually expect to see atomic check/update operations with this kind of thing.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles, Yeah...you're speaking just above my level of comprehension. I'd need to see some examples. But I can say that in this context of my code the 2nd "thread" can't enter the function until at *least* 300us or so after the 1st one, which gives the 1st thread time to set `ISR_locked=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the \ from the last line of the functionLock define.

Comment: Thanks! Wow! 1 hr lost over something so simple.  Oddly enough, my minimal example above, even with the extra \, *does* compile in Code::Blocks....but my code that this question is for is an Arduino program, and it does *not* compile with that extra \.

Comment: @GabrielStaples You probably had a blank line between the two macros in the working case.